# Shiro annotation not working on JavaEE6 project

Tags: security, jsf-2, java-ee-6, shiro

Question: Where is the implementation for JavaEE6?

I'm currently working on a JavaEE6 project and I found out that Shiro's annotation is not working out of the box even though I already configured web.xml and shiro.ini base on the documentation.

This is what I have:

1.) A page:

```
<h:form>
  <h:commandLink action="#{userBean.action1()}" value="Action 1"></h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

2.) Backing bean:

```
@Stateless
@Named
public class UserBean {
    @Inject
    private Logger log;

    @RequiresAuthentication
    public void action1() {
        log.debug("action.1");
    }
}
```

3.) web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

4.) shiro.ini

```
[main]
# listener = org.apache.shiro.config.event.LoggingBeanListener

shiro.loginUrl = /login.xhtml

[users]
# format: username = password, role1, role2, ..., roleN
root = secret,admin
guest = guest,guest
presidentskroob = 12345,president
darkhelmet = ludicrousspeed,darklord,schwartz
lonestarr = vespa,goodguy,schwartz

[roles]
# format: roleName = permission1, permission2, ..., permissionN
admin = *
schwartz = lightsaber:*
goodguy = winnebago:drive:eagle5

[urls]
# The /login.jsp is not restricted to authenticated users (otherwise no one could log in!), but
# the 'authc' filter must still be specified for it so it can process that url's
# login submissions. It is 'smart' enough to allow those requests through as specified by the
# shiro.loginUrl above.
/login.xhtml = authc
/logout = logout
/account/** = authc
/remoting/** = authc, roles[b2bClient], perms["remote:invoke:lan,wan"]
```

But when I click the button, it still performs the action. It should throw unauthorizede exception right? The same is true with other shiro annotations.

Note that if I manually performs the check, it works:

```
public void action1() {
    Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
    AuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken("guest", "guest");
    currentUser.login(token);

    log.debug("user." + currentUser);
    if (currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
        log.debug("action.1");
    } else {
        log.debug("not authenticated");
    }
}
```

Thanks,

czetsuya

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Basically, what I'm missing is the implementation for Shiro's Requires* interfaces so I implemented depending on my needs. For those of you who are interested you can find it here: http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-integrate-apache-shiro-with.html

Comment: The code snippets on the blog are of low quality and didn't cover all annotations and missed the class-level annotations on CDI proxies.

Answer (score 4):

You basically need a [Java EE interceptor](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/interceptor/package-summary.html) in order to scan for the annotations on the invoked CDI and EJB methods.

First create an annotation which the interceptor has to intercept on:

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ShiroSecured {
    //
}
```

Then create the interceptor itself:

```
@Interceptor
@ShiroSecured
public class ShiroSecuredInterceptor implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object interceptShiroSecurity(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        Class<?> c = context.getTarget().getClass();
        Method m = context.getMethod();
        Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

        if (!subject.isAuthenticated() && hasAnnotation(c, m, RequiresAuthentication.class)) {
            throw new UnauthenticatedException("Authentication required");
        }

        if (subject.getPrincipal() != null && hasAnnotation(c, m, RequiresGuest.class)) {
            throw new UnauthenticatedException("Guest required");
        }

        if (subject.getPrincipal() == null && hasAnnotation(c, m, RequiresUser.class)) {
            throw new UnauthenticatedException("User required");
        }

        RequiresRoles roles = getAnnotation(c, m, RequiresRoles.class);

        if (roles != null) {
            subject.checkRoles(Arrays.asList(roles.value()));
        }

        RequiresPermissions permissions = getAnnotation(c, m, RequiresPermissions.class);

        if (permissions != null) {
             subject.checkPermissions(permissions.value());
        }

        return context.proceed();
    }

    private static boolean hasAnnotation(Class<?> c, Method m, Class<? extends Annotation> a) {
        return m.isAnnotationPresent(a)
            || c.isAnnotationPresent(a)
            || c.getSuperclass().isAnnotationPresent(a);
    }

    private static <A extends Annotation> A getAnnotation(Class<?> c, Method m, Class<A> a) {
        return m.isAnnotationPresent(a) ? m.getAnnotation(a)
            : c.isAnnotationPresent(a) ? c.getAnnotation(a)
            : c.getSuperclass().getAnnotation(a);
    }

}
```

Note that the annotations are checked on the target class' superclass as well as the target class may in case of CDI actually be a proxy and Shiro's annotations don't have `@Inherited` set.

In order to get it to work on CDI managed beans, first register the interceptor in `/WEB-INF/beans.xml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/beans_1_0.xsd"
>
    <interceptors>
        <class>com.example.interceptor.ShiroSecuredInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>
</beans>
```

Similarly, in order to get it to work on EJBs, first register the interceptor in `/WEB-INF/ejb-jar.xml` as follows (or in `/META-INF/ejb-jar.xml` if you've a separate EJB project in EAR):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1"
>
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor>
            <interceptor-class>com.example.interceptor.ShiroSecuredInterceptor</interceptor-class>
        </interceptor>
    </interceptors>
    <assembly-descriptor>
        <interceptor-binding>
            <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
            <interceptor-class>com.example.interceptor.ShiroSecuredInterceptor</interceptor-class>
        </interceptor-binding>
    </assembly-descriptor>
</ejb-jar>
```

On a CDI managed bean, you need to set the custom `@ShiroSecured` annotation in order to get the interceptor to run.

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
@ShiroSecured
public class SomeBean {

    @RequiresRoles("ADMIN")
    public void doSomethingWhichIsOnlyAllowedByADMIN() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

This is not necessary on an EJB, the `ejb-jar.xml` has already registered it on all EJBs.

#### See also:

- [Apache Shiro, is it ready for  Java EE 6? - Declarative restriction in bean methods](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html#DeclarativeRestrictionInBeanMethods)

Comment: In the `ShiroSecuredInterceptor` class, in the `hasAnnotation` method, you only check one super class. Is there a reason for that? Just wondering if I need to change it into a recursive check. Anyhow, +1!

Comment: @Jasper: This way I cover proxy classes (EJB, CDI, etc)

Comment: NetBeans is complaining (red underlined error) about a `@PostConstruct` method (`An interceptor for lifecycle callbacks may only declare interceptor binding types that are defined as @Target(TYPE)`), however, my project still builds and the post construct method is still working.
As far as I can tell after some Googling, post construct still works because of the `context.proceed()` statement in `interceptShiroSecurity`, right?

Comment: @Jasper: I don't do Netbeans.

Comment: Resolved the issue by changing `@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })` to `@Target(ElementType.TYPE)` in the `ShiroSecured` annotation.